# How do I remove an engine mount within a metal bracket?

Tags: golf, motor-mounts

This is from a Mk1 VW Golf and is the transmission side engine mount.

I've remove the bracket, but the mount is stuck within it. I've soaked it in WD40 and whacked it a few times with the hammer with no luck.

Would anyone know of any trick to remove it?

Pictures below of old mount in bracket next to new mount.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use an hydraulic press.

Failing that, a long bolt or threaded rod, some nuts and a couple of sockets can work.

The final solution is to cut it to pieces with a hacksaw...